# In UIKit, how do you present a confirmation dialog when the user is swiping to delete a table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

Is there a UIKit equivalent to SwiftUI's [confirmationDialog(_:isPresented:titleVisibility:actions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:actions:)-5lroo)?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller). You must present it on a UIViewController. Use  actionSheet style for example.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "Title",
    message: "Message",
    preferredStyle: .actionSheet
)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
    title: "Delete",
    style: .destructive,
    handler: { _ in
    // delete action
}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
    title: "Cancel",
    style: .cancel,
    handler: { _ in
    // cancel action
}))
present(alert,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil
)
```